# Rails 4 where not sending id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Ruby on Rails 4

My Form was working great when I had Product.all:

```
<div id="ip_voice">
<%= f.label :product_id %><br>
<%= f.collection_select :product_id, Product.all, :id, :name, {prompt: "Select a product"}, {class: "form-control input-lg"} %>
</div>
```

I changed it to a Product.where so I could show different options based on another selection, but this is not sending the :id of the Product. I am new to Rails 4.

```
<div id="ip_voice">
<%= f.label :product_id %><br>
<%= f.collection_select :product_id, Product.where({ category: "ip_voice" }), :id, :name, {prompt: "Select a product"}, {class: "form-control input-lg"} %>
</div>
```

My log, shows the product_id field as "" which is not allowed.

```
Started POST "/mc_question" for x at 2014-04-25 10:05:13 -0700
Processing by QuestionsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"x=", "question"=>{"content"=>"what is going on", "category"=>"ip_video_telephon
y", "product_id"=>"", "active"=>"1", "question_type"=>"MC", "answers_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"content"=>"what", "correct"=>"0"}, "1"=>{"content"=>"is", "correct"=>"1"}, "2"=>{"
content"=>"up", "correct"=>"0"}, "3"=>{"content"=>"", "correct"=>"0"}}}, "commit"=>"Create Question"}
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'x' LIMIT 1
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
(0.0ms)  rollback transaction
```

The div ip_voice is one of six. Onle one is show() the others are hide(). Don't think that matters though. Like this:

```
<div id="ip_video_surveillance">
<%= f.label :product_id %><br>
<%= f.collection_select :product_id, Product.where({ category: "ip_video_surveillance" }), :id, :name, {prompt: "Select a product"}, {class: "form-control input-lg"} %>
</div>

<div id="ip_video_telephony">
<%= f.label :product_id %><br>
<%= f.collection_select :product_id, Product.where({ category: "ip_video_telephony" }), :id, :name, {prompt: "Select a product"}, {class: "form-control input-lg"} %>
</div>
```

HTML Names are the same:

```
<div id="ip_voice">
<label for="question_product_id">Product</label><br>
<select class="form-control input-lg" id="question_product_id" name="question[product_id]"><option value="">Select a product</option>
<option value="2">thisone</option>...
</div>

<div id="ip_video_surveillance">
<label for="question_product_id">Product</label><br>
<select class="form-control input-lg" id="question_product_id" name="question[product_id]"><option value="">Select a product</option>...
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Excuse me for silly question. Did you chose product from select?

Comment: Yes I did choose a product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have six `f.collection_select :product_id` then most likely they all have same `name` attribute for `<select>`. Try to check it in generated HTML.

In that case you have to use different names.

**upd**: Your `question[product_id]` passed as `"question"=>{"product_id"=>""}`

`params` quacks like a `Hash`. So all following values will override previuos:

```
> params = ActionController::Parameters.new(question: { product_id: 1 })
=> {"question"=>{"product_id"=>1}}
> params[:question][:product_id] = ""
=> ""
> params
=> {"question"=>{"product_id"=>""}}
```

Comment: Change the HTML options Name for each? They all have this name="question[product_id]"

Comment: yes. Otherwise last select's value will override all previous.

Comment: Doesn't the name matter for the form to get the param?

Comment: Of course it's matters. That's how they pass values to the server. You can see `question[product_id]` as `"question"=>{"product_id"=>""}` in the params.

Answer (score 1):

Try giving it as a `scope` in your model and use that in `collection_select`

```
#=>product.rb

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :category, -> { where(category: "ip_voice") }
end

<div id="ip_voice">
<%= f.label :product_id %><br>
<%= f.collection_select :product_id, Product.category, :id, :name, {prompt: "Select a product"}, {class: "form-control input-lg"} %>
</div>
```

**Edit**

In your `products_controller.rb` assign the `scope` to an `instance variable` like this

```
def your_method

@product_categories = Product.category

end
```

and use in the form in place of Product.category

```
<div id="ip_voice">
    <%= f.label :product_id %><br>
    <%= f.collection_select :product_id, @product_categories, :id, :name, {prompt: "Select a product"}, {class: "form-control input-lg"} %>
    </div>
```

Comment: It gives undefined method `category' for #<Class:0x00000002b317b0>

Comment: @Pavan I'm not sure I will help somehow. Because you're just moving things around.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the error is gone. The issue is what ck3g said. The names are the same

Comment: @DDDD Ohh,ok.And what do you mean by `the names are the same`?